# Como recorrer columna en vba, saltando campos en blanco?

Tags: vba

Intento recorrer toda una columna para sacar diferencias de horarios, la tengo pero me topo con que en los espacios en blanco, este se detiene.

Lo que intento es saber como brincar un espacio en blanco para seguir con el calculo

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim ve As String
    Dim t0, t1 As Variant
    Dim Total As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    NumRows = Range("Q2", Range("Q2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    MsgBox (NumRows)
    Range("Q2").Select
    For x = 2 To NumRows
        ve = ActiveCell.Value
        t0 = Format(ve, "hh:mm:ss")
        If t0 > "09:00:00" And t0 < "10:00:00" Then
            t1 = Format("09:00:00", "hh:mm:ss")
        Else
            t1 = Format("08:00:00", "hh:mm:ss")
        End If

        Total = Format(TimeValue(t0) - TimeValue(t1), "hh:mm:ss")

        If Total > "07:00:00" Then
            Total = ""
        End If

       Range("AH" & x).Value = Total
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Este es el codigo que llevo hasta ahorita y si me hace el calculo y todo pero en los espacios en blanco es donde se detiene

Answer (score 0):

Si `ve` tiene el `.Value` de una celda, para ver si está vacía:

```
If ve = "" Then

    'Acá el código si está vacía

Else

    'Acá el código si NO está vacía (tiene algún valor)

End If
```

Si además quisieras ignorar cuando sólo tiene espacios, con [`Trim()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions) se eliminan todos los espacios a la izquierda y a la derecha del string.

```
If Trim(ve) = "" Then

    'Acá el código si está vacía

Else

    'Acá el código si NO está vacía (tiene algún valor)

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se te detiene en los espacios en blanco, es que tu código no está bien estructurado, y sin un ejemplo de datos no puedo verlo, pero intuyo que es por esta línea:

```
NumRows = Range("Q2", Range("Q2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

Ahí estás calculando el total de filas del rango Q2 hasta la última fila. El problema es que lo haces con `End(xlDown)`.

Verás, en Excel con VBA hay varias maneras de obtener la **última fila no vacía** de una columna. Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El método `xlDown` equivale a situarse con el ratón en en una celda (por ejemplo `A1`) y entonces presionar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Flecha abajo</kbd>

En nuestro caso, se detendría en la celda `A4`, e ignoraría el resto de filas.

Sin embargo, si a mano te vas a la última fila de la hoja, y presionas <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Flecha arriba</kbd> entonces te posicionarías en la fila 20, que es la última fila con datos en esa columna

Entonces, el proceso a seguir sería:

```
NumRows = Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Esto devolverá la última fila no vacía, y debería incluir tus celdas vacías.